# compiling OpenGL program in cygwin fails

Tags: opengl, cygwin

I'm trying to compile an opengl C program. I'm on a windows platform and I use cygwin. The program is compiled using the following command.

`gcc -o parallel test.c -std=c99 -lglut -lGL -lm`

I have the following packages installed in my cygwin.

[image]

But when I try to compile the application I get the following errors.

```
$ gcc -o parallel test.c -std=c99 -lglut -lGL -lm
In file included from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:144,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from test.c:37:
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:78: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
   68 | void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
      |                                                                              ^~
      |                                                                              )
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:78:78: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
   78 | void APIENTRY gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator *tess,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
      |                                                                              ^~
      |                                                                              )
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:94:74: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
   94 | void APIENTRY gluNurbsCallback(GLUnurbs *nobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
      |                                                                          ^~
      |                                                                          )
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:96:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
   96 | typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUquadricErrorProc)(GLenum);
```

I had another error prior to this, which was

```
$ gcc -o parallel test.c -std=c99 -lglut -lGL -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I attempted to fix this by installing `libGL-devel`, but that resulted in first error. I've been looking for a possible solution and most of them are outdated.

Here is what the include part looks like in the code we were given.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <math.h> // INFINITY
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Window handling includes
#ifndef __APPLE__
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#else
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#endif
```

Comment: It seems you are using the include inside `/usr/include/w32api` instead of the one inside `/usr/include/GL` . That is strange.

Answer (score 0):

install `libGLU-devel`

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/include/GL/glu.h

libGLU-devel-9.0.1-1
```

without that the compiler is using instead

`/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h` that belongs to

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h

w32api-headers-8.0.0-1
```

as the include search order is

```
$ gcc -xc -E -v  -
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../lib/../include/w32api
End of search list.
```

and the last one is `usr/include/w32api`